# live vs. alive vs. living vs. life

Tags: word-choice

Which is the right one to use in each case?

-Variation in life/living/live coloration is shown in Figure X. (or variation in coloration in life is shown in X?)

-Variation in living/alive/live individuals is shown in Figure X.

Thanks for your time

Comment: In your second part-sentence, 'alive' cannot be used prenominally, but the other two adjectives work fine. But I'd change your first example to 'Variation in the coloration of iiving/live specimens is shown ...'.

Comment: More context is needed. Is this one of those [X-Y problems](http://xyproblem.info/)? You are trying to say something, but don't explain what you want to say. Your first example means nothing. Your second could be "living" but as I said - context is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first example doesn't make sense to me with any of the choices. If you mean coloration of something while it is alive, I might recast it as something like "Variation in coloration of living specimens" or "Variation in coloration while alive".

In the second example, I would choose "living". "Alive" in my experience isn't typically applied to nouns as adjectives commonly are, but is rather used as a subject complement (e.g. "I am alive", "it's alive", "you're alive"). "Live" could work, but it's more ambiguous since live can have other meanings and connotations.